# Separating a string into two with a varying point of reference

Tags: java, string

In Java, can I split a `String` from left to right where the left part is an alphabet while the right part is numeric? Assuming the `String` is always a valid string (e.g. all string to be evaluated always starts with an alphabet and ends with a whole number/ no decimal places):

1. `L1293 = ["L", "1293"]`
2. `WMG16 = ["WMG", "16"]`
3. `SP9878558 = ["SP", "9878558"]`
4. `Q12 = ["Q", "12"]`
5. `APMZ1 = ["APMZ", "1"]`

The alphabet part can be virtually range 0 or more length. I've done some tokenizing/looping each character, like checking where the first digit character will appear, and split it there, using `Character.isDigit()`, `String.indexOf()`, and so on. I'm thinking, maybe there is a one-liner for this.

Comment: Should be pretty easy with a regular expression.